# Censored Regression model

Tags: r, optimization, economics

I am considering the following censored regression model. I have a question about my R code.

[image]

Then I obtain likelihood function as follow.
[image: [ logL(\beta,\sigma_u) = \sum_{i\in I} \qty[\mathbbm{1}{y_i > 0}\qty[log\phi\qty(\frac{y_i-x_i^T\beta}{\sigma_u})-log(\sigma_u)] + \mathbbm{1}{y_i = 0}log\qty[1-\Phi\qty(\frac{x_i^T\beta}{\sigma_u})]] ]]

Then i obtain log-likelihood function.
[image]

```
##Data Generation#################################################
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000; u <- rnorm(n);x<- rnorm(n,0,sqrt(2))
y_star <- 1 + x + u
y <- ifelse(y_star > 0, y_star, 0)
data <- data.frame(x,y)

##Censored Regression##############################################
Censored_reg <- function(initial_value,y_in, x_in) {
  f_censored <- function(input, y_in, x_in) {
    sigma <- input[1]
    beta <- input[2:length(input)]
    xb <- cbind(1, x_in) %*% beta
    z <- (y_in - xb) / sigma
    y.indic <- ifelse(y_in > 0, 1, 0)
    
    log_lik <- sum(y.indic*(log(dnorm(z))-log(sigma)) + (1 - y.indic)*log(1 - pnorm(z)))
    return(-log_lik)
  }
  
  result <- optim(par = initial_value, fn = f_censored, y_in = y_in, x_in = x_in)
  return(result)
}
#log_lik <- -sum(y.indic*(log(dnorm(z))-log(sigma)) + (1 - y.indic)*log(1 - pnorm(z)))

# Example usage:
result <- Censored_reg(initial_value = c(2,2,2),y_in = data$y, x_in = data$x)
print(result)
```

I thought it works well, however, the result does not coinside with the results from censReg package.

```
library(quantreg)

rq <- rq(y ~ 1 + x, tau = 0.5, data = data)
screenreg(rq) #library(texreg) # similar to "stargazer"
```

I am very appriciate if you find my error.
Thank you in advance.

Chat GPT does not understand Censored Reg, so pls help me.

Comment: LaTeX is not built into SO.  Perhaps it'd be better if you could render those equations and pasting them as images into SO.

Comment: `pnorm(z)` does not correspond to the formula of the loglik. Should be `pnorm(xb / sigma)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After replacing `pnorm(z)` with `pnorm(xb/sigma)`, I find:

```r
> print(result)
$par
[1] 0.9889646 1.0033864 1.0710261
```

`censReg` gives:

```r
> censReg(y ~ 1 + x, data = dat)

Call:
censReg(formula = y ~ 1 + x, data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x    logSigma 
    1.00337     1.07109    -0.01101
```

The results are almost the same.

Comment: Dear Stéphane Laurent

Thank you for finding my mistake!!
I considered more than an hour.
sincerely appreciate your support : )